# jquery ajax calls are causing a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button in my HTML page which is not part of any form.

```
<input type='button' id='submitter' value='add'/>
```

I have a click handler on it:

```
$('#submitter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var args={}
    $.get('notexists.php', args, function() {alert('what?');}, 'json')
         .error(function(){ alert('error'); });

    return false;
}
```

Now, `notexists.php` does not exist, so the click should alert `error`. But for some reason, The page refreshes with I click the button!

Some experiments I've tried to identify the problem:

1. removed everything from the handler (no return false, no prevent default, no stop prop, no jquery post call - nothing) - the page did not refresh on click, and it should not. the button is not a submit button, and it dont belong to no form.
2. removed teh $.post call - no refresh
3. enabled the firebug's "break on error" feature and tried clicking - refreshed again. so there is no error.
4. changed the post URL to something that exists and works - still refreshing
5. added an "alert" after the $.post call - it did not get called. Seems like the execution breaks at $.post, but there's no error (experiment 3).
6. changed the input to a "div" with the same id. Same results - page gets refreshed.

Can anyone help?

PS: I'm using $.post in MANY other parts of this app, and its working as expected everywhere.

Comment: I'm sure the code you've posted may not cause a page-refresh, please show the complete document-source.

Comment: The page refreshes most probably because the execution doesn't get to the 'return false' statement. Try putting a try/catch block and on catch return false.

Comment: @Pasman return false has nothing to do with it - read my approach 1 and approach 6.

Comment: anywho - I restarted my computer, the SAME CODE is working. Its most certainly teh wierdest thing I've seen. Probably some but I hit in firefox?

Comment: @jrharshath what version of jquery?

Comment: okay, I discovered the final problem - I was wrong when I said "SAME CODE" - I had changed one other thing. I was trying to post an array via ajax. Now, I was relying on `jQuery.fn.map` to do the job. Now `map` creates a jquery object, and not a map. So I diked out `map`, replaced it with `each` and took the array population in my own hands. FIXED.

Comment: just to clarify: the above code is a skeleton, and the actual problem that was bugging me is not reflected here. But I thank you guys for trying to help out. Dr.Molle was right to ask for teh complete source :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked `$('#submitter').length` when you attempt to bind the event? Maybe you have duplicate id's in the dom? Have you got your script running before the closing body tag or inside a jquery doc ready block?

Posting a fuller code sample would help to eliminate the questions I pose.

Comment: The event handler is working - does that not mean that the $('#submitter')'s liength is not zero?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your selector isn't selecting the button, so the event handler is not being applied.

Test your selector by doing something like:

```
 $("#submitter").val('Test');
```

Comment: He mentioned in point 2 that 'removed teh $.post call - no refresh', so the event gets executed